# How to remove the default button highlighting in Safari when using jQuery

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have noticed that under Safari on OS X my default jQuery buttons appear to have a blue glow highlight around them. Just checked and the same thing happens on the [jQuery UI Demo page](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message).

[image: Default button highlighting under Safari]

Under Firefox on my same machine it looks like this

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I can do to remove this under Safari? I would still like the default behaviour.

Comment: have you tried `outline:none` for its `css`?

Comment: @Richard: please look for my updated answer to select the precise button.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

To remove any highlight of inputs that any browser may apply as default action you can always use `outline:none` for their css. in your case it's a `button` element. so this should work:

```
button {
    outline: none;
}
```

[Although it's not recommended to remove the CSS outline.](http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines) as it's is bad for accessibility. (Thanks Robin Clowers for mentioning this)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after.

Comment: This is bad for accessibility: http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Comment: The link does not work because of the extra `/` at the end. If you remove it, the page is found.

Comment: @BishopBarber Thanks for the hint. It is now working.

Answer (score 10):

Try using this

In CSS :

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

In Javascript :

`document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true`);

Answer (score 4):

```
*{
    outline: none;
}

.blah{
    outline-color: blue;
}
```

This will not affect the existed ones. (`.blah`) This works on Google Chrome too.

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TUbjc/

Answer (score 0):

This button has actually an outline property defined. You have to override this. If you inspect this in Firebug you will see the following CSS declaration for this button:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button{outline:none;}
```

Comment: I think, this will hide the button entirely

Comment: @ArashMilani: sorry I meant to say outline:none;